# How to replace in list of dictionaries all dictionaries which occur more than one time with just one new?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to replace in list of dictionaries (every dictionary has same keys with same or different values) all dictionaries `with same values of keys id and type which occur more than 0ne time with just one new dictionary with type group` ?
I can to this by iteration counting existance and put in list all combination with more than one existance and replace, but is there  faster way ?

```
[{id:1, type:1, content:'txt'},{id:2, type:1, content:'abc'},{id:1, type:1, content:'yup'},{id:1, type:1, content:'dmg'}]
```

will become

```
[{id:1, type:'group', content:'txt'},{id:2, type:1, content:'abc'}]
```

Comment: What do you do with `content`?

Comment: Well, show ut what you've got that is either not working or you feel is really bad design. Perhaps you already have the most efficient code, but no-one can't tell without seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

Since searching in lists is slow, it may be worth producing a dictionary of dictionaries as an intermediate, especially if you will be searching by id later. You can convert back to to the list later if necessary.

```
#ld = the list of dictionaries to be processed
nd = {}
for dict in ld:
    i= dict['id']
    if i in nd:
        if nd[i]['type'] != 'group': 
            nd[i]={'type':'group', 'content':'txt'}
    else:
        nd[i]={'type':dict['type'],'content':dict['content']}
```

You would want to test to see if this is actually any faster in the long run.